# How should I configure ReSharper to not complain about null check when parameter marked with NotNullAttribute

Tags: c#, resharper

In the following snippet, ReSharper (I'm on 2017.3.5) will complain that the null check is "always false" and that the exception throwing statement is "heuristically unreachable".

```cs
public void Foo([NotNull] string bar)
{
    if (bar == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

    // do something
}
```

I would argue strongly that the null check is necessary since ReSharper is only an annotation tool and not the compiler. Nothing blocks anyone at run time or even compile time from passing a null.

Is there a way to turn this off, is this a bug, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the same issue in a newly created project?

Comment: @AlexanderKurakin Interestingly enough I can't reproduce in a new application.

Comment: that explains why we were not able to reproduce it. Then, please try removing ReSharper caches for the problem solution as described here https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546989-ReSharper-stopped-working-for-a-single-specific-solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can either turn off the code inspection rule for "Heuristically unreachable code" or change it to Hint.

Goto the Resharper -> options.

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this as it's still a useful inspection. Is this really the only option JetBrains gives us?

Comment: It’s the only option I could find.